# How can I add a custom Parameter to a box in maxscript?

Tags: maxscript

I would like to add a parameter named `initialPosx` that I can use in this manner:

```
a = box
a.initialPosx = n
```

Is there any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read [Scripted Custom Attributes](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-3841BE41-FE47-48ED-92E0-AC125AFEC7FA.htm) and [Scripted Plug-in Clauses](http://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2015/ENU/MAXScript-Help/files/GUID-461915FA-31A2-49CE-84AF-2544B782ACA3.htm) topics. In your case, a trivial example would be:

```
a = Box()
attr = attributes attr (parameters main (initialPosX type:#point3))
custAttributes.add a attr
a.initialPosX = [5, 10, 0]
```